# navigational menu bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, menubar, drop-down-menu

I'm looking to apply a menubar to my website and was thinking something similar along the lines that some of these high street stores use such as maplin.co.uk or argos.co.uk, diy.com.

Where a much greater area of submenu appears..

Any ideas ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a thousand ways to skin this cat.  The simplest is to build the individual div's containing the submenus and then show them using the .hover() event binding on the menu div's.

You could also use a "megamenu" plugin such as http://www.geektantra.com/projects/jquery-megamenu/